# Difference between {} +[] and ({} +[])

Tags: javascript

Why is {} block code in statement 
    {} +[] 
but object in expression
    ({} +[]) ?
Why () change statement to expression?

Comment: Because syntatically code block cannot be within round brackets (not like `({...`, anyway), and that makes it a non-ambiguous thing. But free `{` can be either code block start of object literal start, and parser -- who is unable to do certain lookaheads -- needs to decide early. I guess there is a rule that says "code over literal in general case", something like that.